# How to use main thread when delayElement is used in reactor Publisher

Tags: java, reactive, reactor

How to use main thread when delayElement is used in reactor Publisher.

```java
Mono.just("one")
    .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If I run this code, it will not print "one", because main thread will exit and subscription is done on other thread.

Is there a way to use main thread for subscription of this Mono when I use delayElement?
i.e. wait until "one" is published down the line after 3 seconds, and until subscriber consume it.

Please mind that if I would not have used "delayElement", I could have blocked main thread until it print "one" on screen.

```
Mono.just("one")
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I am aware that I can achieve similar output by using wait and notify (or similar alternative), but what I want is, to use main thread for subscribing element after `delayElement` is called.

*`Mono` class used is imported from `reactor.core.publisher.Mono`*

Consider below example, in which I will use same thread for delay operation of my own implementation.

```java
Mono.just("one")
    .doOnNext(a -> this.myDelayOperation(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

where `myDelayOperation(...)` is

```
private void myDelayOperation(Duration duration) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(duration.toMillis());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `subscribe()` does not block any thread. Use `block()` if this is a blocking call.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but I don't think it's possible. Reactor is a non-blocking API and  it's impossible to implement delay on the same thread without blocking thread. `delayElements` is a time operator, so by default it publishes data on the `Schedulers.parallel()` scheduler.

Comment: @Alex Is there a way to use same thread for delaying operation. I modified my question to add more detail in bottom.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: All these solutions are not recommended for production. Only for testing and learning purpose.

**Debugging: Added Logs on your code**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Method Start Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Mono.just("one")
                    .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("Before delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                    .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("After delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                    .subscribe(val->System.out.println("Final Value: "+val+" Value Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()));
            System.out.println("Method Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

Output:

> - Method Start Thread : main
> - Before delay Value:one and Value Thread:main
> - Method Exit Thread: main
> - Process finished with exit code 0

**Explanation**: Here notice, before printing "After delay value" main-thread got exit. Because delayElement() will not run on main thread and it will run on different thread called "parallel". Before parallel thread completes its operation, main thread got exited, so you are not seeing value "one"

**Solution 1: Making main thread not to exit for some time**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Method Start Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Mono.just("one")
                .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("Before delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("After delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .subscribe(val->System.out.println("Final Value: "+val+" Value Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Wake up Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Method Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Output:

> - Method Start Thread : main
> - Before delay Value:one and Value Thread: main
> - Sleeping Thread: main
> - After delay Value:one and Value Thread: parallel-1
> - Final Value: one Value Thread : parallel-1
> - Wake up Thread: main
> - Method Exit Thread: main
> - Process finished with exit code 0

**Explanation**: Here notice,"After delay value" was printed while main thread was sleep (before its exit). Also note as said earlier delayElement() does not ran on main thread and it ran on different thread called "parallel-1".

**Solution :2 Using block()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Method Start Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Mono.just("one")
                .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("Before delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("After delay Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .block();
        System.out.println("Method Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Output:

> - Method Start Thread : main
> - Before delay Value:one and Value Thread: main
> - After delay Value:one and Value Thread: parallel-1
> - Method Exit Thread: main
> - Process finished with exit code 0

**Explanation:** Here notice, string "After delay value" was printed because we blocked main thread. So until pipeline returns a value it will be blocked.

**Solution 3: Writing custom executor: Highly not recommended**

```
.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Schedulers.fromExceutor(wirteAndCallYourOwnExecutorToBlockCurrentMainThread))
```

**Solution 4: Block using Mono Callable**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Method Start Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Mono.fromCallable(()->{
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Sleeping Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        System.out.println("Wake up Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return "one";
                })
                .doOnNext(next->System.out.println("Received Value:"+next+" and Value Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .subscribe();
        System.out.println("Method Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Output:

> - Method Start Thread : main
> - Sleeping Thread: main
> - Wake up Thread: main
> - Received Value:one and Value Thread: main
> - Method Exit Thread: main
> - Process finished with exit code 0

**> Recommendation: If it was prod, better go with async without blocking. I don't know your complete use case. So, in worst case if required use approach 4 with your own risk.**